# Papyrus/Acceleo jumpstart - classes?

Tags: eclipse, acceleo, papyrus

My company is evaluating M2T technology.  We currently use EA 7.x to model and an in-house template processor to generate code.  We're looking to move to industry standard tooling.  Our primary focus is evaluating Papyrus and Acceleo as they are integrated under Eclipse.  Are there classes in the northeast US (New England - CT, MA, RI, NH, VT, ME) or consultants that could help us set up and evaluate these or any other technologies we should be looking at?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that your question belong to stack overflow as it "invites" people to promote their services but if you are looking for support with Acceleo, here is where you can find commercial support and training.

The Eclipse strategic member, [Obeo](http://www.obeo.fr/pages/training/en), provides MDA training worldwide. This is the company behind [Acceleo](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/modeling.m2t.acceleo) (participate tab) and several other open source projects in the Eclipse Foundation like EEF, EMF Compare, ATL, [Sirius](http://model-driven-blogging.blogspot.fr/2013/03/introducing-eclipse-sirius.html) (which competes with Papyrus in some ways), Mylyn Intent etc.

Disclaimer: I am the leader of Acceleo and I am working for Obeo.